# Passing nested dict payloads from `config` to macros in DBT

Tags: dbt

### Problem

I would like to pass a nested `dict`-of-`dict`s payload from a model's `config` to be used in a macro for processing. The payload should be a dictionary with an arbitrary number of keys, and parameters for each of these keys, e.g.:

```
{{ config(
    payload = {
      'inputs': {
        'input1':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
        'input2':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
      },
      'other_params': {
        'interval': 1,
        'unit': 'hour',
      }
    })
}}
```

However I am encountering an error in passing nested dictionary args in the [`config`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/config) variable to a macro that uses the payload.

When I try to access the items in the input payload, with e.g. `payload.get('inputs')`, I get the following error:

```
Running with dbt=0.20.0
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in model tf_sample (models/intermediate/development/tf_sample.sql)
  'str object' has no attribute 'get'

  > in macro test_payload (macros/test_payload.sql)
  > called by model tf_sample (models/intermediate/development/tf_sample.sql
```

However, I believe this issue is specific to how the config variables are being handled, because if I pass the `payload` `dict` into the macro *directly*, the macro will parse successfully.

### Question

*How can I create a payload `dict` in this format to be passed to a macro?*

### Minimal Working Example of the Problem

Below I have created a MWE to demonstrate the issue:

#### Example macro: loop over the provided `payload.get('inputs')`

```sql
-- macros/test_payload.sql

{% macro test_payload(payload=config.get('payload')) -%}
{% for input, params in payload.get('inputs').items() %}
  -- {{loop.index }}: {{input}}, {{params}}
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
~
```

However this macro will not succeed to pull in the `config.get('payload')` in the way that I am expecting:

#### Example model calling `test_payload()` -- this will FAIL to parse

The below SQL calls the macro in the way I would like (and would expect to work):

```sql
-- model_1.sql --- This will FAIL to parse
{{
  config(
    payload = {
      'inputs': {
        'input1':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
        'input2':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
      },
      'other_params': {
        'interval': 1,
        'unit': 'hour',
      }
    }
  )
}}
-- this fails
{{ test_payload(config.get('payload')) }}

-- this also fails
{{ test_payload() }}
```

#### Example model calling `test_payload()` with an embedded dict; SUCCEEDS

However if I pass the `payload` in directly to the macro `test_payload`, I successfully get the expected output:

```sql
-- model_2.sql --- This will SUCCEED! But it doesn't store the payload in the config :(

{{ test_payload(payload={
      'inputs': {
        'input1':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
        'input2':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
      },
      'other_params': {
        'interval': 1,
        'unit': 'hour',
      }
    }) }}
```

Result:

```
  -- 1: input1, {'param1': False, 'param2': 'test'}

  -- 2: input2, {'param1': False, 'param2': 'test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have the `payload` variable inside `config` for any reason? If that is not the case, you can create variables outside of it and it will work, something like this:

```py
{
  set payload = {
      'inputs': {
        'input1':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
        'input2':  {'param1': false, 'param2': 'test'},
      },
      'other_params': {
        'interval': 1,
        'unit': 'hour',
      }
    }
}

{{ test_payload(payload) }}
```

Then, the macro definition won't need the default `config.get('payload')`:

```
{% macro test_payload(payload) -%}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Right now my workaround is to do as you suggest (although strictly speaking I am supplying to payload directly in the macro call, such that this may be parsed & executed in a *pre-hook*). The desire for having this in the config is that the payload contains model build metadata, which should ideally be retrievable from multiple macros and not have to be set/managed/passed by the analysts/developers. Ideally I would like the SQL developers write as jinja-free and distinct from the metadata in the config as possible.

Comment: The clean state I'd like: developers can write/main config explicitly in YAML/JSON distinct from SQL, and then their SQL is as vanilla standard SQL as possible  containing only business logic that non-dbt developers/analysts understand quickly